# Could browser like tabs made with flex box or css only?

Tags: css, flexbox, width

Need tabs to shrink while the main container doesn't fit all items by width.

Here is expected behavior:
http://adamschwartz.co/chrome-tabs/

But could it be done on pure css, flexbox may be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple. Just `display: flex;` for container, and `overflow: hidden;` for tab items. 
Don't know why my question was downvoted. :(

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tab:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">Google</div>
  <div class="tab">Apple</div>
  <div class="tab">Facebook</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">Google</div>
  <div class="tab">Apple</div>
  <div class="tab">Facebook</div>
  <div class="tab">Chrome</div>
  <div class="tab">Flexbox</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">Google</div>
  <div class="tab">Apple</div>
  <div class="tab">Facebook</div>
  <div class="tab">Chrome</div>
  <div class="tab">Flexbox</div>
  <div class="tab">Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```